# Synaptic Error Message When Selecting "Reload"

Tags: 16.04, synaptic

Never had an issue before with Synaptic.  I installed in on a 16.04 system that I had to install from 15.10 via the "upgrade" process since the 16.04 .iso file will not install on my computer, just sits and icon spins forever.

Anyway, I installed Synaptic Package Manager vis the new Gnome Software Center and when I clicked on "reload" I get an error message where it finds a 15.10 CD-ROM file, even though I am clearly running 16.04.  It says the issue is a security issue and I should not proceed to use it.

When I check "Details" from "Settings" it clearly identifies my system as 16.04.  I tried reinstalling Synaptic, but with no success and the same error message.  Any best ideas of how to fix this?  I did search for this problem but did not find a close match anywhere.

Comment: You refer to three different versions - 15.10, 16.04, and 16.10.  Which version are you actually having this issue on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Software & Updates:

```
Dash >> Software & Updates >> Ubuntu Software >> Installable from CD-ROM/DVD
```

And 'un-check' your rogue entry for the 15.10 CD-ROM. Screenshot to show the location:

[image]

If this does not *fully* resolve the issue check through the other tabs that you can see in the screenshot above ('Other Software' and others) and weed out any references to versions of Ubuntu *other than 16.04*.

Then allow the Repositories to reload...

Comment: Andrew 46, good suggestion.   I did, however, go to the next tab "Other Software" and in addition to checking "Ubuntu Partners" I also checked the "Mulitverse" tab which listed Wiley Werewolf" so must have created my own error.  Thanks for putting me on the right course to fix this.  I reinstalled Synaptic and when I clicked on "reload" I did not get the error message.  Thanks lots.  Will mark this as corrected.

Comment: Good to hear :). I will add in a comment to check all of the other tabs so your question is properly answered...